# Change email css theme at runtime - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#customizing-the-components), to change email css, simply write a new CSS file within the `html/themes` directory and change the  theme option of your mail configuration file.

In my application has two locales. each locale has different css style. my question is: how to change the css theme at runtime according to app locale?

Comment: `config([ "mail.theme" => "sometheme" ])` should work as long as you run it as early as possible (i.e. before generating the message)

Comment: I'm sending email in: `toMail($notifiable)` of Notification. `config([ "mail.markdown.theme" => "sometheme" ])` not working here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos), the solution was to call `config([ "mail.markdown.theme" => "sometheme" ])` just before `$user->notify(new CustomNotification())`.

My fault was calling `config([ "mail.markdown.theme" => "sometheme" ])` in `toMail($notifiable)` of Notification class.

Comment: How is it possible to change the theme at run time when using `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`? In this case any config setting before calling the notification will be reset.

Comment: I did not run into this situation. But the Idea is `config([ "mail.theme" => "sometheme" ])` should work as long as you run it as early as possible (i.e. before generating the message). as apokryfos said.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The Markdown theme is being cached within the Service Worker. Even if we set the `mail.theme`-config before generating the message, it has no influence on the mail.

Answer (score 4):

**This works with Laravel 5.7**

Assuming you have in `/resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/` multiple css files:

```
themes
 >default.css
 >funky_table.css
```

you can set the theme in you build method.

```
public function build()
    {
        $this->theme = 'funky_table';
        return $this->markdown(...
```

This will also work for queries.

Comment: What if you copied the mail folder to storage/ dir for every tenant? Can't you also set the path to templates/css at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Now laravel mailable give option to change theme for particular email using $theme variable in Mailable class.

Here is the documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#customizing-the-css

```
class UserMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $theme = 'tabler';

    /* other code */
}
```

Answer (score -4):

External CSS are mostly blocked by email clients.

So better to use inline css, There is available package [laravel-mail-css-inliner](https://github.com/fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner)

Comment: laravel already has inliner functionality, I want to change css file source at runtime.